# Wiring CJMCU-2317 MCP23017

Tags: expander

I got the `CJMCU-2317 MCP23017 I2C Serial Interface 16 bit I/O Expander Serial Module` to use on a split keyboard as an extension matrix.

[image]

This seems like an all-in-one solution so that I won't have to solder extra capacitors and resistors. I wired Vcc to 5v, GND to GND, SDA to D1, SCL to D0 (Teensy++ 2.0) but I'm not sure about the RESET if I should connect it to Vcc or not and if so should I use some resistor ?

Comment: How are you interfacing between this module and your keyboard? [Microchip has a good datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952a.pdf) on how to properly wire things up.

Comment: The Teensy is the "keyboard" running a firmware built with QMK.  The chip I got have some resistors and capacitors that are usually needed with MCP23017 so I'm looking if someone used this board before to let me know how I should wire RESET.

Comment: Reset can only be active high or low. Flip a coin.

Comment: @Sparky256 thanks, I found some images on Aliexpress reviews where people use it without connecting the RESET, sadly it didn't work for me in any config and I don't have time nor the tools to debug it properly, so I'm switching to 2 Pro micros talking through serial like most split keyboards do. Maybe I can debug this with an Arduino later.

Answer (score 1):

No, I made this mistake on this particular board by connecting reset to vcc through a 10k resistor. The board already does this however, probably expecting you to ground it rather than pull it up yourself.

Measure vcc to reset, you will see a 10k resistance.

I was getting the random resets until I investigated it and found I was halving the resistance by adding another 10k in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

works for me with adress PIN (A0-A2) connected to GND and RESET connected to VCC

Comment: Try to flesh out your answers a bit more than this.  Concise is good, but this is more terse than concise.  Also note that this question is 4 years old.  It's OK to answer old questions, but be aware it bumps them to the top of the queue, so if you answer an old question, try to make your answer as solid as possible so that this will be the last time it gets bumped.